# Mandatory to do a full sync for token creation and contract deployment?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens, synchronization, fast-sync

As the heading says, is it mandatory to do a full sync for token creation and contract deployment?

I have downloaded the etherelum wallet and geth, and right now it is syncing as I write this post. But is it necessary to achieve all the features in the wallet?

What are the disadvantages of a lightly synced wallet (syncmode=light)?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy contracts directly from myetherwallet.com without having to download the Mist/Ethereum wallet.

Answer (score 0):

```
light mode
```

this mode not recommended for use in production.

```
fast mode
```

this mode runing as first launch node, when sync fully, node start full sync. if i right understood documents